# Apigee keystore from Java-callout

Tags: apigee

I am trying to access keystore and key in Java-callout, I have uploaded keystore and key in Apigee using curl command. 
Unable to find a way to reference keys uploaded in Apigee from Java-callout. Has anyone done this before or any idea how it can be achieved.

Regards,
Kamesh

Answer (score 0):

I further investigated, It seems key/certs uploaded at Apigee platform level can not be accessed by Java-callout. It is for security reasons.

Regards, Kamesh

Answer (score 0):

You can include the keystore in the same jar as the java callout and then retrieve it as a resource with getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(".keystore");